# java String, replaceall() but keep case in original string

Tags: java, regex, replace

hello i make a program that can highlight strings into a webview(android) and i stuck at replacing string with colored one, with this piece of code

```
        String[] arr = "LION SAVANA".split(" ");//i split textview string to have words (here we suppose that user entered : "lion savana"


        String finalText = "the lion is a species of mamifer living into the savana"

        for (String ss : arr) {
            if (ss.length() > 2) {
                 ss = ss.replace("*","");
                finalText = finalText.replaceAll("(?i)" + ss, "<b style = \"color:#2575ff\";>" + ss + "</b>");//finally here i replace all lion or savana occurrences by blue ones -> but i not keeps case :(
            }
        }
```

after this loop the text will be "the **LION** is a species of mamifer living into the **SAVANA**" ,colored in blue like expected but with uppercase as i don't expect

Comment: Give an example of an input and output please.

Comment: So what's the actual problem?

Comment: the problem is the following : user enter "FOO" into the textview, but with my code all "foo" or "fOO" of "Foo" will be replaced by "FOO" and i wanna keep original case (upper, lower, or mixed)

Comment: i edited the question with strings to be more understandable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that you provided in your question does the following: it checks the input string case-insensitively for `"LION"` and `"SAVANA"` and replaces each with `"<b style=\"...\">LION</b>"` and `"<b style=\"...\">SAVANA</b>"` respectively.

If you want to get the original word, use backreferences like [here](https://regex101.com/r/eS7fC2/3). With that backreference in use, your `replaceAll` call would look like this:

```java
finalText = finalText.replaceAll("(?i)(" + ss + ")", "<b style = \"color:#2575ff\">$1</b>");
```

Comment: @Noj Yeah, you're right. `$0` would've done the job as well.

Comment: ahaha ok, i think its better to doit with second parenthesis? right?

Comment: @Noj I added them in case you wanted to extend the regex with some other stuff. The paranthesis `()` around the variable `ss` turn it into a capturing group. Since this one is the first capturing group (`(?i)` is not a capturing group), I accessed it with `$1` afterwards. `$0` accesses the whole match, so for example if you used `"(?i)"+ss+" something"` as your regex, `something` would've been added to your replacement as well.

Comment: thank you again, i start to understand a bit more this replaceall function with filters. Now im so happy that my android encyclopedia (based on sparql queries) is better :D...

Comment: @Noj No worries, that's why I answered you. If you ever need to tinker with regular expressions again, I as a programmer myself recommend using a tool like [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 3):

ok i've found how to doit, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189415/java-understanding-the-string-replaceall-method?rq=1)

so finally, i just replaced this line :

```
finalText = finalText.replaceAll("(?i)" + ss, "<b style = \"color:#2575ff\";>" + ss + "</b>");
```

by

```
finalText = finalText.replaceAll("(?i)" + ss, "<b style = \"color:#2575ff\";>" +"$0" + "</b>");
```

**$0** apparently is the word that i want to keep with the same case